# Sqlite FTS3 MATCH OR

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, full-text-search, fts3

I am using FTS3 in sqlite in an android project. The problem is that when I search for the word "or" the database expect more words.

```
"SELECT * FROM words WHERE Palabra MATCH '"+word+"'";
```

This works well except when the word is "or".

How can I search for the word "or" in the database?

Here is the error:

```
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: malformed MATCH expression: [OR] (code 1)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native         Method)
    at    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:845)
    at       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `single quotes`?  See if this helps: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: It is already in single quotes.

Comment: Please post the exact error message the DB Engine is giving you.

Comment: @PM77-1 FTS search expressions are not SQL expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for the word "OR" (or other MATCH expression keywords), you have to quote them (double quotes are usually used for phrase searches, and are harmless for single words):

```
sqlite> select * from t where t match 'NOT OR';
Error: malformed MATCH expression: [NOT OR]
sqlite> select * from t where t match '"NOT" "OR"';
TO BE OR NOT TO BE
```

Searching for the word "or" works just fine, because match expression keywords are case sensitive; it might be easiest for you to use only lowercase search words:

```
sqlite> select * from t where t match 'not or';
TO BE OR NOT TO BE
```

Comment: How to execute a match expression with `"` in its expression?

Comment: @Arjun That is a different question.